# Problem with restoring deleted notification in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to restore deleted notification using Laravel Notification. Problem I am having is that I get error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Notifications\\Notification::withTrashed()
```

because Notification model is in vendor folder and I can't change it. So I need some workaround for that in order for withTrashed method to be available in Notification model. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

Controller

```
public function restoreDeletedNotification(Request $request)
{
    $restore = Notification::withTrashed()->where('id', $request['id'])->restore();

    return response()->noContent();
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/notifications/restore', [\App\Http\Controllers\NotificationController::class, 'restoreDeletedNotification'])->name('restore-notification');
```

Comment: Notification doesn't extend Model so there is no such withTrashed or any other Model query builder stuff. 
Also Notification are triggered, do the work ... and that's it, I don't think that DB is relevant here and any deleted_at. 
Why do you think you can restore it?
How do you deleted it?

Comment: From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#marking-notifications-as-read):  _"You may delete the notifications to remove them from the table entirely"_, the notifications don't implement soft deletes, when you call `delete()` on a notification it will be permanently removed from the table, you cannot restore it.

Comment: I did something similar. I created deleted_at in notifications table and in my method where I delete notification I don't actually delete it but update deleted_at column with Carbon::now() and then when I restore I update deleted_at column to be null. I didn' have to add model and soft deletes. Is that okay solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First note that:**

- By default Laravel Notification's migration file doesn't have a `deleted_at`.
- You are calling `Illuminate\\Notifications\\Notification` which doesn't extend `Model` class so there is no `withTrashed()` method.

**Solution:**

What we are going to do is a workaround. You need to create a `Notification` model (in your `app` directory or `app/Models` if you are using Laravel 8) which extends `Model` then you will use `SoftDeletes` trait.

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

     /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

Now you need to create a migration file to add `deleted_at` column in your `notification` table like so

1. run `php artisan make:migration AddDeletedAtColumnToNotificationsTable`
2. in the migration file you will add

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->softDeletes()->after('updated_at');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('notifications', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn('deleted_at');
    });
}
```

3. run `php artisan migrate`

Now you can use `App\Notification::withTrashed()->where('id', $request['id'])->restore();`.

Comment: I did something similar. I created deleted_at in notifications table and in my method where I delete notification I don't actually delete it but update deleted_at column with Carbon::now() and then when I restore I update deleted_at column to be null. I didn' have to add model and soft deletes. Is that okay solution?

Comment: It's ok, but instead of doing all of these operations manually you can use `SoftDeletes` which will relief from this hassle.